# How set screen saver or sleep at monitor 2 when I use monitor 1, in windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, screensaver

When I work at monitor 1, monitor 2 do nothing, so it  will we good to put in screen saver mode or sleep.
How can I set this in windows 10?

Comment: You can't have individualized settings.

Comment: @ChanganAuto If you work at one monitor for long time then other monitor  can burn pixels, because dont have protection from screesaver or sleep. Any software to solve this?

Comment: That concern was warranted with the old CRT monitors.